# jquery php mysql - how to hide load more button when all itemes displayed

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a code for showing list from database and a `loadmore` button. After all records list is displayed and click on `loadmore` button show empty places. 
[image]

How to hide `loadmore` button once all records displayed?

index.php file:

```
<?php $chinp=$_GET['schinp'];?>
<div  id="schts"></div>
<button id="btnsch">load more</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var chinp="<?php echo $chinp;?>";
  var srchco = 1;
  var offsrch = 0;
  $("#btnsch").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
       url: "search.php",
        data: { srchcoun: srchco, offsrch: offsrch ,chinp:chinp}
      })
      .done(function(msg) {
        $("#schts").append(msg);
      });
    offsrch = offsrch + srchco;
  });

  $("button").trigger("click");
});
</script>
```

search.php :

```
$srchcoun=$_POST['srchcoun'];
$offsrch=$_POST['offsrch'];
$chinp=$_POST['chinp'];
$schql="SELECT id, name, lastname FROM t_users WHERE name LIKE '$chinp' ORDER BY name ASC limit $offsrch, $srchcoun";
$rsch=mysqli_query($conn,$schql);

while ($rch=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsch)){
     $scid=$rch['id'];$snm=$rch['name'];$slnm=$rch['lastname'];?>

<div class="alsu">
<img class="sask" src="pic/<?php echo $scid;?>.png" alt="">
<span class="snm">Name : <?php echo $snm." ".$slnm;?></span>
</div>
<?php }?>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: get count of your list from database, in every load more button compare loaded content with count of list.

Comment: On ajax success check that if your response loaded all the data by comparing `total records count `with the `page number*per page records`, if `total records` becomes equal to `page number*per page records` then hide button with `$('#btnsch').hide();`

Comment: @Yogendrasinh i dont know how to do this

Comment: As per your code it will hit one more click of `load more` button to hide button after loading all the data.

On click of load more in your `search.php` file first count all records by one sql query.
`SELECT COUNT(id) FROM t_users;`

Store this count value in one variable.

Now 
`if (offsrch-1)*srchco = $total_records {
    echo 'noMoreData';
}else{
 Do your while loop code here
}`

At your ajax response change like this.

`if(msg == 'noMoreData'){
 $('#btnsch').hide();
} else {
    $("#schts").append(msg);
}`
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code to hide load more button as per your code.

Replace this code in your first file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  var chinp="<?php echo $chinp;?>";
  var srchco = 2;
  var offsrch = 0;
  var page_num = 0;

  $("#btnsch").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "search.php",
      data: { srchcoun: srchco, offsrch: offsrch ,chinp:chinp, page_num : page_num}
      })
      .done(function(msg) {
        if(msg == 'noMoreData'){
          $("#btnsch").hide();
        } else {
          $("#schts").append(msg);
        }
      });
      page_num = page_num + 1;
    offsrch = offsrch + srchco;
  });

  $("#btnsch").trigger("click");
});
</script>
```

Now add this code in your search file.

```
<?php
$srchcoun=$_POST['srchcoun'];
$offsrch=$_POST['offsrch'];
$chinp=$_POST['chinp'];
$page_num=$_POST['page_num'];

$total_records = 0;
$totalschql="SELECT id FROM t_users WHERE name LIKE 'krishna' ORDER BY name ASC";
if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$totalschql))
    {
        $total_records=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    }

$last_records_count = ($page_num) * $srchcoun;
if($last_records_count >= $total_records) {
    echo 'noMoreData';exit();
} else {

    $schql="SELECT id, name, lastname FROM t_users WHERE name LIKE '$chinp' ORDER BY name ASC limit $offsrch, $srchcoun";;
    $rsch=mysqli_query($conn,$schql);

    while ($rch=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsch)){
         $scid=$rch['id'];$snm=$rch['name'];$slnm=$rch['lastname'];
?>
    <div class="alsu">
    <img class="sask" src="pic/<?php echo $scid;?>.png" alt="">
    <span class="snm">Name : <?php echo $snm." ".$slnm;?></span>
    </div>
    <?php }?>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Try this and let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: i try this and works but when i change var srchco = 1; to var srchco = 2; it does not  hide

Comment: it works, thanks. but when i click search button first does not show anything but load more button and when i click on it show first two resaults

Comment: Replace this line `$("$btnsch").trigger("click");` with this line `$("#btnsch").trigger("click");`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `$('#myButtonId').hide();` in ajax part after you load the entire data from database.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function get_rain_data_list(is_load_more=0){

    if(is_load_more!=0){//if is_load_more is not 0 then get offset data from btnlod attr
     offset = $('#btn_load_more_rain').attr("data-offset");
    }else{ //set offset =0 when is_load_more is 0
     offset = 0;
    }
    var id  = $('#id').val();

    var countShow = 0;
    if(fromDate!=''){
         countShow = 1;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url+"rain_data_list_ajax",
        type: "POST",
        data:{offset:offset,propertyId:propertyId,fromDate:fromDate,toData:toData}, 
        dataType: "JSON",
        beforeSend: function() {
            show_loader();
        }, 
        success: function(data){
            hide_loader();
             // console.log(data);
            $('.proprty_load_more_btn').remove();//remove load more button 
            if(offset==0){ //clear div when offset 0
                $("#append_rain_list").html('');
            }
            if(data.no_record==0){//show data in div when no previous record 
                $("#append_rain_list").html(data.html_rain);
                 $("#add_count").html('');
                if(countShow){
                    //$("#add_count").html(data.count+data.record);
                }
            }else{
                //append data when already record show in view
                $("#append_rain_list").append(data.html_rain);
                $("#append_load_btn").append(data.btn_html);
                $("#add_count").html('');
               if(countShow){
                    $("#add_count").html(data.count+data.record);
                }
            }
        },
    }); 
}
```

```html
<div id="append_rain_list"></div>
<div id="add_count"></div>

<?php 
 function rain_data_list_ajax(){

  $limit = 6;
  $is_next = 0;
  //get and set offset
  $offset = $this->input->post('offset');
  $data['property_id'] = decoding($this->input->post('propertyId'));
  $fDate = sanitize_input_text($this->input->post('fromDate'));
  $tDate = sanitize_input_text($this->input->post('toData'));

  $new_offset = $limit+$offset; //pr($data);
  //set where
  $where = array('property_id'=>$data['property_id']);
  //set select field to get
  $data['limit'] = $limit;
  $data['offset'] = $offset;
  //get count of records
  $dataView['total_count'] = $this->Property_model->get_rain_count($data);
  //get records 
  $dataView['rain_list'] = $this->Property_model->get_rain_list($data);
  ///lq();
  //check for load more btn
  //pr($dataView);
  if($dataView['total_count']>$new_offset){
  $is_next =1; 
  }
  $btn_html = '';
  if($is_next){
  //if is next =1 set load more button in btn_html
  $id = "btn_load_more_rain";
  $btn_html = '<div class="col-sm-12 text-center pt-20 proprty_load_more_btn"><button class="login-btn load load_more_btn" id = "'.$id.'" data-offset ="'.$new_offset.'" data-isNext ="'.$is_next.'" >'.lang('load_more').'</button></div>';
  }
  //load view with data
  $html_rain = $this->load->view('test1',$dataView,true);
  $response = array('status'=>1,'html_rain'=>$html_rain,'btn_html'=>$btn_html,'count'=>$dataView['total_count'],'record'=>lang('recod_found'));
  //flag for no record 
  $no_record=1;
  if(empty($dataView['rain_list'])){
  $no_record = 0;
  }
  $response['no_record'] = $no_record;
  echo json_encode($response);die;
 }
?>
```

Comment: what is this !?

Comment: load more pagination